# Change type of mix elements in list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, types

I have a list:

```
g=['Зенит','3', 'Спартак', '1', 'Спартак', '1', 'ЦСКА', '1', 'ЦСКА', '0', 'Зенит', '2']
```

I need to change for int elements to int. Resulting like that:

```
g=['Зенит',3... ]
```

How?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a short method that `try`'s the conversion and either returns an `int` or the value itself and combine it with a list comprehension:

```
g=['a','3', 'b', '1', 'c', '1', 'd', '1', 'e', '0', 'f', '2']

def tryInt(text):
    """Tries to convert text to int. Either returns an int or text"""
    try:
        return int(text)
    except: # catchall for any error whatsoever
        return text

g2 = [tryInt(value) for value in g]

print(g2)
```

Output:

```
['a', 3, 'b', 1, 'c', 1, 'd', 1, 'e', 0, 'f', 2]
```

See: [Python Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#errors-and-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
g = [int(value) if value.isdigit() else value for value in g]
print (g)
```